# Angular http client adds unnecessary url path when a request is from a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, typescript

```
// item.service.ts  
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
private http: HttpClient;
...
getItems(): Observable<Item[]> { 
  let baseUrl = 'api/items/';
  let url = baseUrl + 'getItems'

  return this.http.get<Item[]>(url);
}

// app.module.ts   
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "i", loadChildren: './item/item.module#ItemModule' }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ItemService]
})
export class AppModule { }

// item.module.ts    
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'list', component: ItemsCmp }
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [ItemsCmp]
})
export class ItemModule { }

// items.cmp.ts   
@Component({...})
export class ItemsCmp { 
  constructor(private item: ItemService){ 
    let result$ = this.item.getItems(); // http request from the lazy loaded module
  }
}
```

When the `ItemCmp` makes a http-request through an instance of `ItemService` the url is **i/api/items/getItems**, but expected is **api/items/getItems** How can I remove the lazy-loaded part (i) of one?

(My app uses a standard Bearer HttpInterceptor that is provided in the AppModule, but it does not change url)

Comment: Did you try to change: `baseUrl = 'api/items/` to `baseUrl = '/api/items/'`?

Comment: @cyrix, yes, it helped, thank you